# Truncate Text with JavaScript but keep original accessiable to screen readers

Tags: javascript, html, wai-aria

I have text that may break onto multiple lines but should be truncated with an `...` added to the end if the maximum character count is exceeded.

Example - Original text = `A link to something` Truncated text = `A link ...`

Is there a way to store the original text so that it is accessiable to screen readers?  I have been looking into aria attributes but am not sure if those can help in this situation.

Here is a fiddle to my current code, but I do think it is very accessible:  http://jsfiddle.net/9s57b/

Here is my HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="js-text">A link to something</a>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var element = document.querySelector('.js-text'),
  // innerText for IE, textContent for other browsers
  text = element.innerText || element.textContent,
  textArray = text.split(''),
  textArrayLength = textArray.length,
  maxCharacterCount = 7,
  newText = ''; 

if (textArrayLength > maxCharacterCount) {
  for (var i = 0; i < maxCharacterCount; i++) {
    newText += textArray[i];
  }
}

element.innerHTML = newText + ' ...';
```

Comment: The title attribute?  `<a href="#" class="js-text" title="A link to something">A link...</a>`

Comment: @LDMediaServices I was wondering if that would work.  Is that considered accessible?

Comment: Set required text in title. You can use http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/ for customized tooltip

Comment: Might be able to do this strictly in css with  text-overflow: ellipsis

Comment: I'm not an expert in screen readers, but I'm pretty sure they rely heavily on the title tag when it comes to anchors.  Other elements not so much.

Comment: @MattR Unfortunately `text-overflow: ellipsis` does not seem to work for strings that break on multiple lines.  I know my fiddle does not demonstrate multiple lines, but that is the reason I am not using `text-overflow: ellipsis`